# php function returning null value

Tags: php, recursion

I am recursively searching a tree node for its parents, and then trying to return its parent categories in an array.

The function receives and passes itself an array of each parent which is finally returned.

Even though this array has elements, the statement before the return when viewed outside the function is `nul`.

To make it work, I just made the parameter by reference. But why is it always `nul`?

Here is my code:

```
function getParent($id,$parents){ // to work changed this to getParent($id,&$parents)

    if($id < 2) { // 1 is the Top of the Tree , so job is done
        return $string;    
    }

     $child = DB::fetchExecute((object)array( // pdo query for category to get parents
     'sql'   => "category",
     'values'=>  array($id),
     'single'=>  1,
     'debug' =>  0)
     );

    $parent = DB::fetchExecute((object)array( // pdo query for parents info
        'sql'   => "category",
        'values'=>  array($child->native_parent_category_id),
        'single'=>  1,
        'debug' =>  0)
    );
    $string[]= "<li>$parent->name ($parent->native_category_id)</li>
        ";        

    getParent($parent->native_category_id , $parents);    
}

// call function
$array = array();
$returnString = getParent($id,$string);

var_dump($returnString,$array); // will both be NULL, or if called by Reference $array has the goods

?>
```

Comment: $string is being returned without ever being set if `$id < 2`. You're only setting it but never passing it to the recursed call

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
function getParent($id,$parents){
```

To:

```
function getParent($id,$parents, $string){
```

And change:

```
getParent($parent->native_category_id , $parents);
```

To:

```
getParent($parent->native_category_id , $parents, $string);
```

The scope of `$string` only exists in the function as it runs - so, if you rerun the function, it will reset all the variables within it. You need to send the variable each time you rerun it.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare `$string` before function, and inside function, use `global $string;` at top.